# Texbox inside canvas of html5

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

Can I insert a textbox inside the canvas using HTML 5? If yes, please tell me how to insert a textbox inside the canvas? At present I am using rectangle to implement my functionality but it is not the way i am looking forward so please help me to create textbox using KINETICJS in HTML 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really simple.

You have to put your textbox inside a div and then change the div position. In order to do this, under your body tag:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="mytext"> 
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div> .....
```

Under your head tag:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        #mytext {
            position: absolute;
            left: 36%;
            top: 725px;
            z-index: 999;
        }
    </style>
```

By changing the left and top value you can place the textbox on your canvas.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can place an input or text area in front of a canvas element so that it appears to be inside, but there is no way to embed an input into a canvas since a canvas is just a space in which to paint pixels via JavaScript.

I'm fairly certain that you can embed inputs in SVG in some browsers, however, and might even be able to transform them (rotate, shear, etc.).

Comment: can we get any sources links to learn about textboxes inside canvas

Comment: You can embed HTML in SVG using [`foreignObject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Element/foreignObject), transforms should be applied.